# ConvNet pooling and RG flow

Tags: convolution, neural-networks, statistical-mechanics, computer-vision

I have a physics/mathematics background and am learning about NNs.

The 'pooling' operation applied to layers of CNNs seems to me to very closely resemble 'blocking' (eg decimation or 'majority rule') in Statistical Physics (eg the Ising model on a lattice).

There we impose it analytically to relate the parameters of the finer- and coarser-resolution theories, and obtain a renormalisation group equation that roughly says that we are indifferent to fine (short-wavelength) details and care about larger-scale behaviour.

In CNNs we seem to impose it numerically for a fixed number of iterations (layers) after a predefined convolution with a filter whose weights we will adapt through training.

My question is: is there any analogy between these two operations, besides the obvious one? Is it possible for CNN pooling to lead to RG-type flow, perhaps representing microscale (resolution)-invariance and macroscale (angular distance)-invariance? [my made-up terminology, probably poor].

Comment: It looks like this has been considered before, to some extent: [An exact mapping between the Variational Renormalization Group and Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3831)

I will try to tackle the paper over the next few days and post an answer to my own question, if the paper helps me understand a connection and nobody beats me to it.

Comment: I think you might be interested in 2021 book "The Principles of Deep Learning Theory". It has chapter 4 "RG Flow of preactivations" and chapter 8 "RG Flow of the Neural Tangent Kernel".  They don't apply to pooling alone, but to the entire flow in a CNN.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for recommending it; I will dive in when I get a chance. Interesting that others have had the same idea!